# Nodejs - Promise.all performance compared to standard async/await for each function

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm still trying to understand Promise.all so wrote a quick simple script to see the performance difference between Promise.all compared to awaiting each function using while loops.

I was under the assumption Promise.all would be a lot faster as it runs functions in parallel but my script seems to be telling me otherwise.

Is this too simplistic and am I missing something?

```
const p1 = async () => {
  let x = 0
  
  while(x < 100000000) {
    x++
  }
  return x
}

const p2 = async () => {
  let y = 100000000
  
  while(y > 0) {
    y--
  }
  return y
}

const p3 = async () => {
  let z = 0
  
  while(z < 200000000) {
    z = z + 2
  }
  return z
}

const run1 = async () => {
   console.time("Parallel")
   
   const [res1, res2, res3] = await Promise.allSettled([p1(), p2(), p3()])
   console.log(res1.value, res2.value, res3.value)
   
   console.timeEnd("Parallel")
}

const run2 = async () => {
   console.time("Sync")
   
   const res1 = await p1()
   const res2 = await p2()
   const res3 = await p3()
   console.log(res1, res2, res3)
   
   console.timeEnd("Sync")
}

run1()
// run2()
```

**The result**

[image]

Comment: Async functions might get executed in parallel; however, CPU work is not parallel (not multi-threaded). You would observe the promises.all benefit if your async functions were waiting on network IO.

Comment: `Promise.all` doesn't run functions. It merely monitors already existing promises.

Comment: Using the `async` keyword is useless if not accompanied by `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont forget that js is single threaded so computations on the main thread comes at the expense of other functions so for example p1 and p2 run "in parallel" but on the same event loop.

```js
const p1 = async () => {
  let x = 0
  while(x < 100000000) {x++}
  return x
}
const p2 = async () => {
  let y = 100000000
  while(y > 0) {y--}
  return y
}
const p3 = async () => {
  let z = 0
  while(z < 200000000) {z = z + 2}
  return z
}

const run1 = async () => {
   console.time("Parallel")
   const [res1, res2, res3] = await Promise.all([p1(), p2(), p3()])
   console.timeEnd("Parallel")
}
const run2 = async () => {
   console.time("Sync")
   const res1 = await p1()
   const res2 = await p2()
   const res3 = await p3()
   console.timeEnd("Sync")
}

const p4 = async () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    timeout = setTimeout(() =>  {
      resolve(true);
    }, 100);
  });
}
const p5 = async () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    timeout = setTimeout(() =>  {
      resolve(true);
    }, 150);
  });
}
const p6 = async () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    timeout = setTimeout(() =>  {
      resolve(true);
    }, 200);
  });
}

const run3 = async () => {
   console.time("Parallel2")
   const [res1, res2, res3] = await Promise.all([p4(), p5(), p6()])
   console.timeEnd("Parallel2")
}
const run4 = async () => {
   console.time("Sync2")
   const res1 = await p4()
   const res2 = await p5()
   const res3 = await p6()
   console.timeEnd("Sync2")
}

(async()=>{
  await run1()
  await run2()
  await run3()
  await run4()
})()
```

As you can see in the second example for not computational intensive tasks Promise.all takes as long as its longest promise, and chaining as long as the sum of all promises.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I was looking at this from the wrong angle. Am I right in thinking that when doing multiple database queries; let’s say inserting rows into 3 different tables, doing it via Promise.all will yield faster results as opposed to running each query synchronously?

Comment: @Dally From what i understand of what you're asking, yes, Promise.all is faster than chaining asynchronous requests. As i said, Promise.all takes as long as its longest promise, and chaining as long as the sum of all promises. Wishing you luck